# export command not found (using putty)

Tags: c, linux, putty

hi i searched information about this and didn't find any that solve my problem.

I connected remotely to server of my College using putty , now i'm trying to create a dynamic library , using the command to set the path:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/fred/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

it says: "export: command not found"

i compiled my code using this:

```
gcc -I../include -L../lib -o printer printer.c -llprprint
```

(it alowed me to compile code library file .so and  include file that i have done, all work fine)

so the problem is i want to run ./myProgram it says cant find my library or its not exists.

i wonder if the prolem is in the path? how i make export works? please help

Comment: What happens when you just type in export?  Does it come up with a load of screen output, or does it still say command not found?

Comment: @Nick what do you mean?

Comment: @Welshboy it still say command not found

Comment: When you:

cd /
then run find . -name export 

what comes up?

Comment: Did you click the link in my comment?

Comment: /etc/exports
/lib/udev/udisks-dm-export
/lib/udev/udisks-lvm-pv-export
...
and many more

Comment: @Welshboy find command not found

Comment: @Nick il check it now

Comment: sorry this is still show me old error (cant run ./myProg) even when i did  bash -c "export foo=bar; echo \$foo" with this parameters:

bash -c "export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/fred/lib; echo \$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not entirely sure, but your shell may not be bash.
Try running `which sh` and see what shell you are using.
Chances are, you might be using tcsh or ksh

Another neat way to get your shell is by using
`cat /etc/passwd | grep <username>` (use your username instead of `<username>`)
This should show you your shell

If you find out that your shell isn't bash, but you want to use bash, you could use `chsh`
This allows you to change the default shell

Comment: did command which sh it shows me "/bin/sh"
and when use cat it shows me for be correct i use cat /etc/mypass
it says "no such file or directory"

Comment: no, `/etc/passwd` is a file that stores all user information. You shouldn't be using your password instead of `passwd`

Comment: oh man! it ask for login shell what should i put there?

Comment: If you're unsure, just hit ctrl+c to terminate. If you know the path to bash, you can enter that path in the prompt provided. I think bash is generally found in `/bin/bash` if it exists

Comment: i want that the bash will see my library, should i put the location of it?

Comment: You have two options, either find out the analogous operation of `export` for your shell, or change your shell to something (bash) which understands `export`

Comment: super noob question, what shell understand export?

Comment: You would be looking for bash :)

Comment: Here's what you do..`cd /bin` and then type `ls bash`..if you get a result, then your university server has the bash shell..so now, you can confidently execute `chsh` and then when it asks for a path to bash, you enter `/bin/bash`..another way you can obtain path to bash is by executing `which bash`

Comment: hehe ok thanks everybody who helped i think im gona catch it

Comment: ok i did that now it says 
chsh: user 'glizerinol' does not exist in /etc/passwd

Comment: its my user  "glizerinol"

Comment: Not sure how to solve that ;(

Comment: ok il try figurate it out thanks you man!